# TypeScript "TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y'" error even though type is defined

Tags: arrays, typescript

In my code, I'm trying to access the `type` property of a `React.ReactElement` array element. Even though I've defined the array to contain `React.ReactElement` children, I get an error trying to access an array element's `type` property unless I cast the array element to be of the type `React.ReactElement`.

Here's my code:

```
const getChildren = (
    children: (React.ReactChild | React.ReactElement)[]
) => {
    console.log((children[0] as React.ReactElement).type)  // this line works
    console.log(children[0].type)  // this line breaks
}
```

and here's the error that I get:

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'.  TS2339
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with React but I'm assuming that `React.ReactChild` has no attribute named `type` and this is the reason you are getting the error.

Typescript compiler has no idea of knowing which of the types (`React.ReactChild` or `React.ReactElement`) your item is unless you explicitly tell the compiler which one is it. This is why your first line in the function works, because you explicitly tell the compiler that the argument passed in the function is `React.ReactElement[]` or at least the first element in the array is the argument of type `React.ReactElement`.

If you know that elements in an array will always be a type of `React.ReactElement` then I suggest you to change the function argument type to be

```js
const getChildren = (children: React.ReactElement[]) => {/* ... */}
```

otherwise you should check it which of the types is it to avoid runtime errors:

```js
const getChildren = (children: (React.ReactChild | React.ReactElement)[]) => {
  if (children[0] instanceof React.ReactChild) {
    console.log(children[0].type);
  }
}
```